# Сохранение картинок

Tags: curl, php, изображения

Есть метод, который определяет ссылку картинки и загружает ее в папку. Скажите, как сохранить картинку методом CURL с указанным размером?

```
$name = $mas_dan[$k]['Manufacturer Part Number'];
$img = $mas_dan[$k]['Image'];
$ch = curl_init($img);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);
 $out = curl_exec($ch);
$image = "published/publicdata/U0010117NEW/attachments/SC/products_pictures/$name.jpg";
$img_sc = file_put_contents($image, $out);
curl_close($ch);
```

Comment: > Скажите, как сохранить картинку методом CURL с указанным размером?

Что под этим подразумевается? Выбрать изображения с определенным размером? Заресайзить изображение? Уменьшить его качество?

Answer (score 1):

Для сохранения картинок завернул данный код в функцию и дополнил все рабочей библиотекой classSimpleImage.php.

И получил что-то вроде этого:

```
classSimpleImage.php';  
include 'classSimpleImage.php';

/*Сохранение изображения*/  
function image_load($url_files,$nm){  
if (preg_match("/http/",$url_files)){  
    $ch = curl_init($url_files);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);  
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_BINARYTRANSFER,1);  
    $out = curl_exec($ch);  
    $image_sv = '/httpdocs/conell.ru/published/publicdata/U0010117NEW/attachments/SC/products_pictures/'.$nm.'.jpg';  
    $img_sc = file_put_contents($image_sv, $out);  
    curl_close($ch);     
}  
return $img_sc;  
}      
/*Изменение размера изобаржения*/  
 function resize_img_enl($nm) {   
   $folder = '/httpdocs/domen.ru/published/publicdata/U0010117NEW/attachments/SC/products_pictures/';  
   $image = new SimpleImage();  
   $image->load($folder.$nm.'.jpg');  
   $image->resizeToWidth(150);  
   $save_img = $image->save($folder.$nm.'_enl'.'.jpg');  
  return $save_img_enl;   
 }
```

Работает замечательно, спасибо [[@Etki](/users/16095/etki)](/users/16095/etki) за совет!